# Unable to update using Details view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Below written code for details view, and i am trying to update the data.
when i click on edit button, fields changes to textbox then changing some values for testing purpose, when i click on update there is no change in previous data.
 didn't get any error regarding code, and also debug line by line but there is no problem, it executes very well but no data update in data base.

do i need some more code to do or some thing else remain.

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvstudentdetails" runat="server"   EmptyDataRowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
                    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  AllowPaging="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" 
                 AutoGenerateRows="False" 
                  onitemupdating="DetailsView1_ItemUpdating"  
                    onitemupdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" onmodechanging="DetailsView1_ModeChanging1">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />          

                <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></EmptyDataRowStyle>

                <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
                 <Fields>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StudentID" Visible="True" InsertVisible="True" >                               
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblStudentID" Text='<%# Eval("stud_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblstud" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("studname") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditstudname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("studname") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="InsertstudnameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("studname") %>' MaxLength="10" />
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Student Contact Number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblstudnumb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("stud_numb") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditstudnumb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("stud_numb") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtinsertstudnumb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("stud_numb") %>' MaxLength="10" /></InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parent Contact Number">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblparenumb" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pare_numb") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditparenum" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pare_numb") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtinsertparenum" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("pare_numb") %>' MaxLength="10" /></InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("address") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditaddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtinsertaddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("address") %>' MaxLength="10" /></InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblcity" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("city") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditcity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("city") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtinsertcity" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("city") %>' MaxLength="10" /></InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblgender" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditgender" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gender") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtinsertgender" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("gender") %>' MaxLength="10" /></InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Id">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("email") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txteditemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' MaxLength="10" /></EditItemTemplate>
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtinsertemail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("email") %>' MaxLength="10" /></InsertItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>




                 </Fields>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderTemplate>Personal Details</HeaderTemplate>
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                 </asp:DetailsView>
```

below code on item updating command

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    con = cn.connection();
    //DataKey key = dvstudentdetails.DataKey;
    TextBox txtstudname = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditstudname");
    TextBox txtstud_num = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditstudnumb");
    TextBox txtpare_num = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditparenum");
    TextBox txtaddress = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditaddress");
    TextBox txtcity = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditcity");
    TextBox txtgender = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditgender");

    TextBox txtemail = (TextBox)dvstudentdetails.FindControl("txteditemail");

    try
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd =new SqlCommand( "UPDATE tblstudentdetails SET studname ='" + txtstudname.Text + "', stud_numb ='" + Convert.ToDouble(txtstud_num.Text) + "', pare_numb ='" + Convert.ToDouble(txtpare_num.Text) + "', address ='" + txtaddress.Text + "', city ='" + txtcity.Text + "', gender ='" + txtgender.Text + "', email ='" + txtemail.Text + "' WHERE stud_id='" + 1 + "'",con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageLabel.Text = "Record updated successfully";
        loaddetails();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageLabel.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
  protected void DetailsView1_ModeChanging1(object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    dvstudentdetails.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
    loaddetails();

}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug and find out issue?

Comment: Well. If not error, it should insert data.

Comment: The value for `stud_id` is really `1` for that record? You could put a breakpoint on the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` line and take a look at `cmd.CommandText`, to see if something in the query is not as you expect (and copy/paste it to test it directly in your database) .

Comment: yes, stud_id is 1 and query is fine,

Comment: am i  firing wrong event or something else?